# How do you iterate through all elements of a QML ListModel?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, listmodel

How can you iterate through all the individual `ListElement`(s) of a `ListModel` in QML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was surprised how hard it was to find an answer to this question myself.  Since I could not find a related question already on SO, I'm answering it myself here.

```
for( var i = 0; i < listModelID.rowCount(); i++ ) {
    console.log( listModelID.get(i).<yourPropertyName> );
}
```